# Веб браузер в Delphi

Tags: delphi, iwebbrowser2

Вопрос, как сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки грузилась страница, при этом из определенной папки, например, в D. Лежит прога в d:/text текст, при этом если я захочу перенести прогу, то будет отображать, что файлы не найдены ..

```
procedure TForm5.SpeedButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 webbrowser1.navigate('D:\text\2.htm');
end;
```

вот так работает, как надо, если же убираем `d:\` то страницу перестает видеть.

Answer (score 3):

Насколько помню, `TWebBrowser` плохо работает с относительными путями в методе `navigate`.
Как вариант `ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)` и ini-файл/реестр с указанием пути к файлу.

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с последним ответом, самое оптимальное

```
webbrowser1.navigate(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'data\\text2.htm');
```

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант - залей файл на хостинг, например, hosting.hg/text2.htm

```
procedure TForm5.SpeedButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  webbrowser1.navigate('hosting.hg/text2.htm');
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

Тоже вариант как написал

> Code_Bryant
>
> Как вариант - залей файл на хостинг, например, hosting.hg/text2.htm
>
> `procedure TForm5.SpeedButton2Click(Sender: TObject); 
> begin 
>     webbrowser1.navigate('hosting.hg/text2.htm'); 
> end;`

Но и еще можно сделать просто закинуть свой *.htm страницу в папку с браузером! Это тоже работает! Когда будешь перемещать папку она будет там же!